# Sum and Filter Function in Power BI not working

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 10 columns Day 1 - Day 10 and need to total Days 1-5 and then Filter on a specific column.
The below measure works when adding all the columns I need, but when I try to add in a Filter, I get an error.

What am I missing here?

```
Comp Within Complete 5 days = 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 1]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 2]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 3]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 4]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 5])
```

When I add in the Filter, I get the error.

```
    Comp Within Complete 5 days = 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 1]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 2]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 3]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 4]) + 
SUM(Completed[Closed Day 5])

Filter(Table, Table[Category] = "Servicing"))
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid syntax would be this

```
Comp Within Complete 5 days =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Completed[Closed Day 1] )
        + SUM ( Completed[Closed Day 2] )
        + SUM ( Completed[Closed Day 3] )
        + SUM ( Completed[Closed Day 4] )
        + SUM ( Completed[Closed Day 5] ),
    FILTER (
        Table,
        Table[Category] = "Servicing"
    )
)
```

but it's not clear what you want to achieve with this since you are aggregating a different table than the one you are filtering on.

You have to provide sample data to make your problem clear. And your 10 columns Day 1 - Day 10 indicate that your data model hasn't been set up properly but needs unpivoting.

Comment: I would say it's quite normal to filter a different table than the one you are aggregating. That's the whole point of data models with dimensions and fact tables.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a sketchy table design. You should have something more like (Date, Amount, etc) then you can just use DATESBETWEEN or similar.